# Preg match where id attribute changes by 1

Tags: php

I want to get the innertext of each anchor. And then print the results. The "ctl" in the id attribute is increased by 01 each time though.

I have to match them by the id attribute because of the page these anchors are located.

How could I do that?

```
<a id="ctl00_mainContent_rpLeaderboard_ctl01_hypServiceRecord" href="/Stats/Reach/default.aspx?player=DJ+DarkRecon">DJ DarkRecon</a>

<a id="ctl00_mainContent_rpLeaderboard_ctl02_hypServiceRecord" href="/Stats/Reach/default.aspx?player=X+PR+Legacy+X">X PR Legacy X</a>

<a id="ctl00_mainContent_rpLeaderboard_ctl03_hypServiceRecord" href="/Stats/Reach/default.aspx?player=Forgiver2">Forgiver2</a>
```

Comment: Use a HTML parser

Comment: Do you just want the innertext?  If so, I would imagine the attributes are irrelevant.

Comment: I have to match them by the id attribute because of the page these anchors are located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather quick solution using an HTML parser:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<a id="ctl00_mainContent_rpLeaderboard_ctl01_hypServiceRecord" href="/Stats/Reach/default.aspx?player=DJ+DarkRecon">DJ DarkRecon</a>
<a id="ctl00_mainContent_rpLeaderboard_ctl02_hypServiceRecord" href="/Stats/Reach/default.aspx?player=X+PR+Legacy+X">X PR Legacy X</a>
<a id="ctl00_mainContent_rpLeaderboard_ctl03_hypServiceRecord" href="/Stats/Reach/default.aspx?player=Forgiver2">Forgiver2</a>
');
$i = 1;

while($i < 4) {
    var_dump($dom->getElementbyId("ctl00_mainContent_rpLeaderboard_ctl0{$i}_hypServiceRecord")->nodeValue);
    $i++;
}
```

There are a numerous ways to go about this via a parser, I'm hoping this will give you some sort of a start.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
preg_match_all('~<a[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>~i', $text);
```

Of course, that works just in the easy example you've given. For a more complex html problem, regex isn't the best answer.

EDIT:

```
preg_match_all('~<a id="([^"]*)"[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>~i', $text);
```

If you need the id too.